# Pagination eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I want to paginate ordering by linkscount em ASC...

The table pages:

```
----------------------
id | name
----------------------
1  | Globo
---------------------- 
2 | Google
---------------------- 
3 | MC Donalds
---------------------- 
4 | Habibs
```

The query to FIRST PAGE RESULTS (order/query is OK):

```
            $pages = Mypages::where('pages.author_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->orderBy('linkscount', 'desc')
                ->leftJoin('links', 'links.page_id', '=', 'pages.id')
                ->selectRaw('pages.*, count(links.id) as linkscount')
                ->groupBy('pages.id')
                ->take(2)
                ->get();
```

The query TO PAGINATE (order/query is not ok):

```
                $pages = Mypages::where('pages.author_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->orderBy('linkscount', 'asc')
                ->leftJoin('links', 'links.page_id', '=', 'pages.id')
                ->selectRaw('pages.*, count(links.id) as linkscount')
                ->groupBy('pages.id')
                ->where('pages.id', '>', $id)
                ->take(2)
                ->get();
```

This query, don't return nothing, it was to return "MC Donalds"...

$id = LAST ID DISPLAYED.

Comment: This is pretty far off from real SQL queries, but if you are selecting all records (pages.*) and only grouping by pages.id you would normally get a SQL error that you have column that are invalid because they are not aggregated or part of the GROUP BY. Then again, this isn't real SQL and I don't know how these languages would handle it.

Comment: Why not just use the [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination) function, which will do all of that for you?

Comment: Because I use queries that eloquent don't recognize

Answer (score 0):

Like Jacob H said in the comment, this isn't a real SQL, because the group by function need to have all the columns of the query that you have in the select except the functions like counts, sums, etc.

For this example you need to put the pages.name and pages.id in the group by

```
$pages = Mypages::where('pages.author_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->orderBy('linkscount', 'asc')
            ->leftJoin('links', 'links.page_id', '=', 'pages.id')
            ->selectRaw('pages.id, pages.name, count(links.id) as linkscount')
            ->groupBy('pages.id', 'pages.name')
            ->where('pages.id', '>', $id)
            ->take(2)
            ->get();
```

And if you are sending the correct `$id`, everything seems ok.